# How enable aggregation for the calculated fields in the kendo ui dataSource?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-datasource

I am using the following template to create alculated field in the kendo dataSource.

```
model: {
    fields: {
        Qty: {type: "number"},
        Amt: {type: "number"},
    },
    Total: function (item) {
        return (item.Qty * 1) + (item.Amt * 1);
    },
```

Now I want to show footer with the summary for the Total field in the kendo ui Grid

here is the full example http://jsfiddle.net/Casufi/wavkpdg1/6/
Please advise how to configure dataSource to provide aggregated summary for the Total field.

Comment: Got solution http://jsfiddle.net/Casufi/wavkpdg1/8/

Comment: Example with the working export to Excell
http://jsfiddle.net/Casufi/3qx377u5/15/